# Get highlighted text from active window without using clipboard

Tags: java, c#, python, clipboard, clipboarddata

I have a Windows application that prohibits to copy text. But I need somehow to copy (or just output) highlighted text
I tried this (python) , but it just doesn't copy text from those application

```
import pyautogui as pya
import pyperclip
import time
import keyboard


def copy_clipboard():
    pya.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return pyperclip.paste()

while True:#making a loop
    try:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
                print('You Pressed A Key!')
                pya.doubleClick(pya.position())
                var = copy_clipboard()
                print(var)
                break
            else:
                pass
    except:
            break
```

If someone has an idea how to do it (python, java, c#) - please help me :)

Comment: What kind of an application is your source application? WinAPI desktop, WPF or something else?

Comment: @mnistic , this is probably WinAPI. By the way I think that EM_GETSEL would be nice desigion, but I don't know how to code it.

Comment: It's going to be `WM_GETTEXT` followed by `EM_GETSEL` after you get the window handle, something like here: https://github.com/gschizas/KeyboardDump/blob/6e6114ef380779e2264256526d05cd3940b4f5f6/hotkey.py You have to hope that the source window does not have these messages blocked / disabled of course.